# Expo App environments for Dev, UAT and Production

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, app-store

I have a React Native app built in Expo that connects to a Rest API. There are three environments for the rest api - dev, uat and production as below (example).

```
dev = https://dev.myapi.com/api
uat = https://uat.myapi.com/api
prod = https://prod.myapi.com/api
```

Depending on where the app is being used it needs to connect to the correct environment.

```
Running in the Expo Client = Dev API
Running in TestFlight or Internal Testing for the Play Store = UAT API
Running in the App Store or Play Store = Production API
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Follow below Steps**

1. Install **expo-constants** package. To install the package run the below command.

   **npm i expo-constants**
2. Add **environment.js** file and paste below code.

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const localhost = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'localhost:8080' : '10.0.2.2:8080';

const ENV = {
  dev: {
    apiUrl: 'https://dev.myapi.com/api',
    amplitudeApiKey: null,
  },
  staging: {
    apiUrl: 'https://uat.myapi.com/api',
    amplitudeApiKey: '[Enter your key here]',
    // Add other keys you want here
  },
  prod: {
    apiUrl: 'https://prod.myapi.com/api',
    amplitudeApiKey: '[Enter your key here]',
    // Add other keys you want here
  },
};

const getEnvVars = (env = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel) => {
  // What is __DEV__ ?
  // This variable is set to true when react-native is running in Dev mode.
  // __DEV__ is true when run locally, but false when published.
  if (__DEV__) {
    return ENV.dev;
  } else if (env === 'staging') {
    return ENV.staging;
  } else if (env === 'prod') {
    return ENV.prod;
  }
};

export default getEnvVars;
```

3. Accessing Environment Variables

```js
// Import getEnvVars() from environment.js
import getEnvVars from '../environment';
const { apiUrl } = getEnvVars();

/******* SESSIONS::LOG IN *******/
// LOG IN
// credentials should be an object containing phone number:
// {
//   "phone" : "9876342222"
// }
export const logIn = (credentials, jsonWebToken) =>
  fetch(`${apiUrl}/phone`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jsonWebToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
  });
```

4. To create the builds use the below commands.

**Dev - expo build:ios --release-channel dev**

**Staging - expo build:ios --release-channel staging**

**Production - expo build:ios --release-channel prod**

Now that Expo supports config file as app.config.js or app.config.ts, we can use the dotenv. Check this: https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/#using-a-dotenv-file

- [Refer link](https://alxmrtnz.com/thoughts/2019/03/12/environment-variables-and-workflow-in-expo.html)

Comment: Does this method allow for dynamic update of the URL used by the app at run-time?  Or is it determined at build-time?  If it is at build-time, is there any way to have the app determine the server URL at runtime?

Comment: This is determined at build time because it's based on release channel names, to determine server at runtime maybe you can create a Backend Endpoint to check if that user or device should be running on which environment.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using different Release Channel names,
lets say you have created 3 release channels this way:

```
expo publish --release-channel prod
expo publish --release-channel staging
expo publish --release-channel dev
```

then you can have a function to set environment vars accordingly:

```
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';

function getEnvironment() {
  if (Updates.releaseChannel.startsWith('prod')) {
    // matches prod*
    return { envName: 'PRODUCTION', dbUrl: 'ccc', apiKey: 'ddd' }; // prod env settings
  } else if (Updates.releaseChannel.startsWith('staging')) {
    // matches staging*
    return { envName: 'STAGING', dbUrl: 'eee', apiKey: 'fff' }; // stage env settings
  } else {
    // assume any other release channel is development
    return { envName: 'DEVELOPMENT', dbUrl: 'aaa', apiKey: 'bbb' }; // dev env settings
  }
}
```

Refer to [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/release-channels/) for more info!

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using Expo sdk 46(or any newer version), you can do the following way

1. Rename the app.json to app.config.js
2. Add API URL under extra property

```
export default () => ({
  expo: {
    name: '',
    slug: ''
    extra: {
      API_URL: process.env.API_URL || null,
    },
    // ...
  },
});
```

We can access this API using expo constants like this(wherever we want).
Don't forget to import constants from Expo.

```
const myApi = Constants.expoConfig.extra.API_URL 
axios.get(myApi).... // using API END POINT
```

For Local development to access API you can do it in two ways

1. API_URL="http:// localhost:3000" expo start
2. Just comment the Contants.expoConfig..... and directly paste local URL
   like  const myApi = "http:// localhost:3000"

And in eas.json

```
{
  "production": {
    "env": {
      "API_URL": "https://prod.example.com"
    }
  },
  "staging": {
    "env": {
      "API_URL": "https://staging.example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Once we run eas build the appropriate API endpoint will be set.
Refer to the same in Expo documentation
https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/environment-variables/

Comment: For now, there is no option for creating an EAS config file in javascript using "eas build:configure" command. It will create "app.json" file by default. To quickly change it to "app.config.js", change the name and add "export default" at the beginning of the file.